# Taking input from the Keyboard in Assembly (TASM)

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I've already got the program that takes input from the keyboard and print it on the screen but I am having problem understanding few lines of the code,

here is the code,

```
     MOV DS, AX
      MOV ES, AX        ;Why Move AX content to ES ???

      MOV DX, OFFSET PNAME      ; PRINT NAME: 
      MOV AH, 09H               
      INT 21H                   


      MOV BYTE PTR SNAME, 21    

      MOV DX, OFFSET SNAME      
      MOV AH, 0AH
      INT 21H

      MOV SI, 0002              

      LEA DX, SNAME[SI]         ; PRINT NAME ENTERED
      MOV AH, 09H
      INT 21H
```

Why we first move 21 of size byte into SNAME ???? 
How Result of Keyboard input interrupt service automatically stored in SNAME instead of AL ???

Comment: You would expect the input in AL if you call 1H (to read one character from the input device). Here, you are printing a string to standard output device (9H), then you're reading a string from the standard input device (0AH), and then you're printing the input received.

Comment: Why we first move 21 of size byte into SNAME ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your favorite MSDOS function reference.

You can find there [this](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm):

```
Format of DOS input buffer:

Offset  Size    Description     (Table 01344)
00h    BYTE    maximum characters buffer can hold
01h    BYTE    (call) number of chars from last input which may be recalled
(ret) number of characters actually read, excluding CR
02h  N BYTEs   actual characters read, including the final carriage return
```

So, 21 sets the maximum number of character that you can read from the keyboard into the buffer.

As for "`How Result of Keyboard input interrupt service automatically stored in SNAME instead of AL ???`", the question is unclear.

Comment: i mean to say how the dos knows the keyboard must be assigned to the Variable SNAME , if there were more than one variable whom would it be assigned ?

Comment: What do you mean by how? You give DOS the address of SNAME and it uses it to write to, unsurprisingly, SNAME.